# Remote stop Service without Admin Permissions

Tags: service

I know that you can stop services with the SC command, but that requires Admin rights on the target machine.  I have used the SC SDSET command to modify the SDDL set for the service in question.  Now I have it so that the non-admin user can stop and start the service locally.  This command will not work remotely.  User VPN's into the network and I have tried several combinations to use the SC Stop command and always get Access is Denied.  I tested it locally by giving the user account Logon Locally, and the user can only stop/start the 2 services that I modified, but cannot do it remotely.

Tried creating scripts that would run the SC Stop command on the remote Server, but is being accessed via a share and therefore seems to detect that the command is not local. I have tried a local (to the VPN user's PC) script that calls a script on the remote Server that runs the SC Stop command and it still fails.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I know that there are trust issues involved between your machine and the remote. It depends on the VPN client OS. You have to open up some DCOM ports and modify permissions and it isn't very easy.